# /blog for the Blog listing and /blog/%postname% for the Blog Post, mod_rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently working on a site which requires the sitename/blog for Blog Listing Page and sitename/blog/%postname$ for the Blog posts.

My current mod_rewrite rule is following.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/blog/        /blog/  [R=301,L]
```

Any, How to make this possible?

Comment: Don't mess with the `.htaccess`, these are basic WordPress settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a blank page with the slug `blog`; the title doesn't have to be the same.
2. Go to *Settings > Customise > Static front page > Posts page* and select the page you just added.
3. Go to *Settings > Permalinks* and select *Post name* or use `/blog/%postname%/` in *Custom structure* if the former is incorrect.